# Chi-square/G-test/Fisher exact with replicates

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I want to use Fisher exact or G-test/Chi-squared (the choice depends on the numbers of observations in a particular case) to test difference in species frequencies between and within replicated groups of observations. Here are some toy-data

```
    1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3
spec1   1   2   1   3   5   4
spec2   4   4   6   0   1   1
spec3   10  12  9   9   10  10
```

The first row denotes samples. The first digit of a sample ID represents a replicated group and the second one represents a replicate. Here is an example of the dataset collapsed for the first species.

```
spec1   1   2   1   3   5   4
others  14  16  15  9   11  11
```

It's easy to compare replicates within groups, because we can simply perform a bunch of pair-wise tests and apply some multiple-comparison p-value adjustment, but how do we treat replicates when we compare different groups? Can we just combine them into one sample?

I'm aware of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121032/chi-square-test-with-replicates) post, but it has no answers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question :/ Can you try and rephrase? For example, in the sentence "Can we just combine them into one sample?", what is "them" referring to? "replicates" or "groups"?

Comment: @winni2k Excuse me for a delayed response. Yes, the question is about handling replicates in a chi-square-like test. Regarding your question: *"them"* refers to *"replicates"*. Since chi-square is a goodness of fit test, by *"merging"* I've implied estimating a single discrete distribution given a group of samples (i.e. replicates) drawn from that distribution (in this particular case, the later can be approximated by a multinomial distribution or a Dirichlet-multinomial)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169142/g-test-vs-pearsons-chi-squared-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Testing species frequencies

I understand the OP's first question to be "Are the proportions of species 1, 2, and 3 identical across all six columns?" I think a chi-square test of independence of rows and columns would be applicable if the cell counts are sufficiently high (that's a whole other topic).

## When can count data be combined?

My reading on this topic suggests that one can combine count data if one can show that the data (replicates) are homogeneous. Zar [1] describes combining multiple tests of goodness of fit (section 22.6) or multiple 2x2 contingency tables (section 23.4) through a *heterogeneity chi-square*. This test is performed by calculating the chi-square statistics for each replicate separately, and then comparing the sum of those chi-square statistics to the chi-square statistic one derives from pooling the data. Zar describes the steps in detail and [this page](https://www.stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=chi-square%20test%20for%20homogeneity) does so as well.

[1]: Jerold H. Zar. 1999. Biostatistical Analysis, 4th edition.